# Laravel 8 looped job chaining order

Tags: php, laravel

I have two jobs that need to run one after the other. These two jobs are chained, and the entire chain is run twice.

```
$models = array(1,2);
foreach($models as $model) { 
    Bus::chain([
      new getRecommendations($model),
      new processRecommendations($model),
    ])->dispatch();
}
```

By my understanding, this is how the queue should run:

getRecommendations(1)
processRecommendations(1)
getRecommendations(2)
processRecommendations(2)

Instead, the queue is running as below:

getRecommendations(1)
getRecommendations(2)
processRecommendations(1)
processRecommendations(2)

[image: Screenshot of PHP Artisan]

How do I get the jobs to run the way I need them? I don't want processRecommendations to wait until all instances of getRecommendations are done before they run.

These are the job classes:

```
class getRecommendations implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        // do stuff

    }
}


class processRecommendations implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Bus::..`?

Comment: Also, I think there is an additional comma at the end of line `new processRecommendations($model),`  - not sure if that's ok.

Comment: @kiner_shah From the [Laravel 8 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-chaining)  

"To execute a queued job chain, you may use the chain method provided by the Bus facade."  

I doubt the comma is an issue, the official docs have the last comma as well...

Comment: You are calling `Bus::chain` in a `foreach` loop. Not sure how Laravel handles it but you can try first creating an array of all the tasks inside the loop and then call `Bus::chain` once after the loop and pass that array to it.

Comment: I have tried the same and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: I will post the solution shortly

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai any luck?

Comment: I have tried it but I am not able to figure out

Comment: @Dickinson can you find any solution?

Comment: @amin No, sorry